# Where do the symbols for the Spheres in Mage: the Ascension come from?

Tags: world-of-darkness, mage-the-ascension, art

The *Mage: the Ascension* line has adopted symbols that represent each Sphere. My question is where they are from? Not in-world - I am interested what is the real world source of these.

[image: Image showing all the symbols for Correspondence, Entropy, Forces, Life, Matter, Mind, Prime, Spirit, and Time]

---

I would also want to clarify that I do not believe these were created specifically for Mage. As a game tries very hard to incorporate real world mystic concepts and practices and concepts.

I have seen some of the symbols in other places, for example the Prime symbol (perhaps an ornate Greek Psi character) shows up in some video games as a "spell particle effect" or otherwise something mystic among other thing.

As an example, the video game *Arcanum: Of Steamworks and Magick Obscura* features the symbol for the Fire magic college. It is not merely a Psi character - it is the same trident shape with a line through it:

[image: Image of the Fire symbol in Arcanum - very visually similar to the symbol for Prime in Mage.]

The same game also features the Life symbol for the Phantasm College a Greek Psi with soft curves, rotated 90 degrees anti-clockwise and ends in a "hook":

[image: Image of the Phantasm symbol in Arcanum - very visually similar to the symbol for Life in Mage.]

Arcanum also has the Summoning which has the Entropy symbol - I can only describe it as an Arabic numeral "4" with a big flourish for the middle horizontal dash to make it 1. curved a bit 2. styled as an arrow pointing to the right:

[image: Image of the Summoning symbol in Arcanum - very visually similar to the symbol for Entropy in Mage.]

I am sure I have noticed others like the Matter and Time symbols in other contexts but I cannot give examples right now. Perhaps the only one I *do not* remember seeing elsewhere is the Spirit symbol.

All in all, it appears that many works tap into the same source for these but I am not sure where to search for it and how.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As [Guybrush McKenzie’s fine answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/193126/4563) notes, Wikipedia claims these are alchemical symbols depicted in *Symbols, Signs, and Signets* by Ernst Lehrer, 1950. However, I haven’t been able to find a copy of this book to double-check that, and I don’t think anyone at Wikipedia has either: they don’t cite the book itself but rather [this forum post](https://www.everything2.com/index.pl?node_id=812282). However, our own @JasonWodicka does have a copy, and [confirms that it contains these symbols](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/193118/where-do-the-symbols-for-the-spheres-in-mage-the-ascension-come-from/193128?noredirect=1#comment523013_193128), drawn by Lehrer from his own references:

> OK, I've finished the cross-referencing. All the symbols are in the book—and, in fact, all but the tenth sphere are on page 79, looking very much as they appear in Mage. (The tenth sphere is on page 78, and is labeled as the alchemical symbol for “Vinegar”) Given that these were the versions drawn by Ernst Lehner, from his varied references, I think it's very plausible that the *Mage* illustrators were using these exact drawings as reference, though we can’t prove it.

Wikipedia also includes a list of Latin names for the alchemical ideas that the symbols represent, citing [this page’s scans of *Medicinisch-Chymisch und Alchemistisches Oraculum*, Ulm, 1755](http://www.levity.com/alchemy/alchemical_symbols00.html). This book is conveniently *well* into the public domain, and the Internet Archive has [a full scan of it](https://archive.org/details/b30522535/mode/2up), making it easy to verify (convenient, since actual reprints of it apparently go for over $300).

Notably, no one is claiming that White Wolf actually referenced these particular sources for *Mage: The Ascension*. Lamed-Ah-Zohar’s forum post claims he just happened to find *Symbols, Signs, and Signets* in an old-book store while looking into the symbols, not that he has any knowledge that White Wolf used it. It’s completely unclear how *Medicinisch-Chymisch* was found. Point is, we don’t know *exactly* how White Wolf found these symbols—but most likely, it was a process rather similar to Lamed-Ah-Zohar’s, whoever was tasked with this went to a library or old-book store, and just used whatever happened to be available. Remember, *Mage* was published the same year Tim Berners-Lee released the world’s first web browser, so information was a lot harder to come by.

Anyway, here’s the full list, using *Mage* symbols from [The Unofficial White Wolf Wiki](https://whitewolf.fandom.com/wiki/Mage:_The_Ascension_symbols), modified to fit on our site, next to the actual symbols from *Medicinisch-Chymisch*, for comparison. I’m using the levity.com scans since they’re in black and white, and are somewhat indexed. I also include a column with the Unicode characters for each concept, where available, just to show that the ones from *Mage* aren’t (apparently) the most prominent ones.

| *Mage* Sphere | *Medicinisch-Chymisch und Alchemistisches Oraculum* | Unicode |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image: Correspondence symbol] Correspondence | Amalgam¹ [image: Amalgama] | `U+1F75B` |
| [image: Entropy symbol] Entropy | Rot [image: Putredo] | `U+1F764` |
| [image: Forces symbol] Forces | Boiling² [image: Ebullitio] |  |
| [image: Life symbol] Life | Arrangement, combination; agreement, pact; union [image: Compoſitio] |  |
| [image: Matter symbol] Matter | Amalgam¹ [image: Amalgama] | `U+1F75B` |
| [image: Life symbol] Mind | The Sun, cf. gold³ [image: Sol, ſ. aurum] | `U+2609` ☉ (“sun”) |
| [image: Prime symbol] Prime | Essence [image: Essentia] |  |
| [image: Spirit symbol] Spirit | Fumes, smoke, steam [image: Fumus] |  |
| [image: Time symbol] Time | Dust, powder [image: Puluis] | `U+1F74B` |
| [image: Tenth Sphere symbol] Tenth sphere | Vinegar⁴ [image: Vinum mortuum] | `U+1F70A` `U+1F70B` `U+1F70C` |

1. What, if any, distinction was found (or imagined) by White Wolf between the two amalgam symbols, used for Correspondence and Matter, is unknown. *Medicinisch-Chymisch*, at least, makes no such distinction. White Wolf may simply have liked both designs.
2. The symbol used in *Mage* for Forces does match up nicely with a fairly common—though not common enough to get Wikipedia or Unicode treatment—alchemical symbol for boiling. It doesn’t, however, match up very well with the *Medicinisch-Chymisch* symbol for *ebullitio*, which adds another leg and splits up the crossbars between the two legs.
3. “Sol” is “the Sun,” and “aurum” is “gold.” The “ſ.” here is a long s (`ſ` not `f`), and in particular, [it is in Blackletter font, indicating it is German and not Latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/17220/1088). It stands for “ſiehe,” meaning “see,” and has a similar usage in German as “cf.” does in English. So this is basically “Sun, see also gold,” where gold is listed as “Aurum, sol,” or “Gold, Sun.”

   Alchemists heavily associated gold with the Sun and often used the astrological symbol for the sun, `U+2609` ☉, to mean gold. Unicode also includes `U+1F71A`  as the alchemical symbol for gold, which in some fonts looks rather similar to that for the Sun. Amusingly, Unicode *also* includes a very similar “see also” note on `U+1F71A` , pointing to `U+2609` ☉.

   My *guess* here is that the idea is the “Aurum, sol” entry is for symbols used for both gold and the Sun, while “Sol, ſ. aurum” is for symbols that are used *only* for the Sun, and don’t mean “gold.” The “ſiehe” is reminding the reader that if they’re looking for symbols for the Sun, they should also consider all the symbols for gold. Unfortunately, the author doesn’t provide a German translation as he does for so many other entries, most likely because “sol” and “aurum” were rather well-known Latin words, so this is somewhat speculative on my part.

   Also, note that the Wikipedia list associates Mind with [image: solutio, folvere] which is a *large* stretch, and simply wrong considering how close the penultimate “Sol, ſ. aurum” entry is. This may have just been misunderstanding the rather dense table, since “solutio” is immediately after “sol, ſ. aurum” and the entries kind of run into one another (plus the lack of translation on “sol, ſ. aurum” could make it all look like one entry).
4. *Medicinisch-Chymisch* is confusing here, as it has separate entries for “acetum ſ. vinum mortuum” and “vinum mortuum, ſ. acetum.” “Acetum” and “vinum mortuum” both mean vinegar—the author even translates both as “Eſſig,” which is German for vinegar—and it’s a mystery why these two entries are different, or why our Tenth Sphere symbol only appears in the latter. If this book’s entries were in English, we’d have “acetic acid, cf. vinegar” and “vinegar, cf. acetic acid” as if those were different things.

   Unicode’s `U+1F70A` , for the record, is *Medicinisch-Chymisch*’s entry for “acetum, ſ. vinum mortuum,” i.e. not the entry with the Tenth Sphere symbol. Things sort of like `U+1F70B`  are listed for “acetum deſtillatum,” distilled vinegar I suppose, but the symbols have a top crossbar, [image: U+1F70B except the vertical part of the cross looks like a T instead of an I], or they have only two of the four dots, [image: two symbols that look like U+1F70B except they have only the bottom two, or the top two, dots, respectively].

Comment: Oh, this is great - thanks for doing this extra legwork! I will also have to find that book, the symbol repositories I found online had less similar versions of many of these.

Comment: Re your point 3; I suspect (but can't prove) that the long s is an abbreviation for "sans", without, which *might* account for it appearing twice with different word order.

Comment: @postmortes It would presumably be the Latin _sine_ rather than the French _sans_, but that’s a great thought! Unfortunately, as far as I can tell “vinum acetum” and “vinum mortuum” both mean vinegar, so I don’t know what distinction might have been made. Also while “sun, without gold” might make some sense considering how entwined they were, I would expect then an entry for “sun with gold” or something... Huh, which there is, under “Aurum, sol.” Even has the more familiar circle-with-a-dot.

Comment: True, *sine* is much more likely given this is Latin, well caught!  I suspect we need an actual Latin speaker for more, but you can make vinegar from things other than wine so *acetum* and *vinum acetum* might differ.  There is also such a thing a "vinegar mother" which is a mix of bacteria and yeast that produce vinegar (usually living on something alcoholic) which might create a difference between 'dead vinegar' and (heh) undead vinegar...

Comment: Luckily, SE has a site for those—I’ll ask after I’ve properly woken up and had some tea (but I repeat myself). My digging on my own suggests “s.” definitely could mean _sine_, but could also mean many other things, and in any event I haven’t been able to confirm that “ſine” is a thing. The only example of “ſ.” I could find was for “ſecundus,” “2nd,” which does not seem to fit here.

Comment: @postmortes Latin SE came through for us—even though it turned out to be German! The “ſ.” is short for “ſiehe,” “see,” in the sense of “see also.” Still doesn’t explain what distinction is being made between “acetum” and “vinum mortuum”—the author even translates both to the same German word for vinegar—but it does clear up a lot of the confusion.

Comment: Oh, hey! I happen to have a copy of Symbols, Signs & Signets on my shelves (a Dover Publications reprint), and I'm doing the cross-referencing against that forum post. I'll get the results here in a few minutes after some meetings. (Sorry for posting early, I hit enter on this while I was drafting it.)

Comment: OK, I've finished the cross-referencing. All the symbols are in the book - and, in fact, all but the tenth sphere are on page 79, looking very much as they appear in Mage. (The tenth sphere is on page 78, and is labeled as the alchemical symbol for "Vinegar")  Given that these were the versions drawn by Ernst Lehner, from his varied references, I think it's very plausible that the Mage illustrators were using these exact drawings as reference, though we can't prove it.

Comment: @JasonWodicka Awesome, I’ll note that.

Comment: @JasonWodicka By the way, if you were so inclined, I’d love to see photos/scans of 78-79 here and include those in my table. Does Lehrer make some kind of distinction between the two symbols for amalgam?

Answer (score 11):

### They are derived from alchemical symbols

Several sources, including those cited on [the Wikipedia article for *Mage: The Ascension*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mage:_The_Ascension), match the sphere symbols to specific alchemical symbols. Some of the sources cite version of the symbols found in the 1950 book *Symbols, Signs and Signets* by Ernst Lehner (though don’t claim this was the source used by White Wolf), but you can also find many of them in online collections of alchemical symbols.

The *Mage* versions have enough in common with these that this rings true, though they are adaptations: sometimes they use part of a more complex symbol, or change it by adding or removing elements. Only a few are relatively unchanged, and some of the listed “matches” are more like inspiration than a single source.

The list given on Wikipedia and in at least one of its sources is:

- Correspondence: *amalgama* (amalgam, as in a substance)
- Entropy: *putredo*/*putrefacto* (to rot)
- Forces: *ebbulio* (to boil)
- Life: *compositio* (composition)
- Matter: *almagama* (amalgamation, as in the process)
- Mind: *solutio* (to dissolve) - though this doesn’t seem correct ([see KRyan’s more comprehensive answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/193128/35508))
- Prime: *essentia* (essence)
- Spirit: *fumus* (fumes)
- Time: *pulvis* (dust or powder)
- Tenth sphere: vinegar (in *Ascension*); *The Sorcerer’s Crusade* offers a different symbol, which Wikipedia’s list claims is a combination of the symbols for stone and distillation. (Note that the older post used as a source for these matches doesn’t include either version of the tenth sphere symbol.)

As for their use in *Arcanum*, that game was released in 2001, many years after the release of the first edition of *Mage: The Ascension* in 1993. Also of note is that *Arcanum* was produced by Troika Games, who went on to produce *Vampire: The Masquerade - Bloodlines* in 2004, which might indicate some crossover awareness of *Mage*. This is just speculation, though; and of note the symbols you specifically cite are some of those which most closely resemble the original alchemical symbols, especially the entropy symbol.

Comment: OK, this makes sense, I suppose. I doubt the alchemical symbols have a single representation - alchemists were famously secretive about their work and did not others to "steal" it. Having a single standard symbol set to work with that everybody used completely unchanged, *especially* centuries in the past doesn't seem plausible.

Comment: Have you been able to confirm this by actually checking a copy of _Symbols, Signs, and Signets_? I had found the same claim, but couldn’t verify it from that book.

Comment: @VLAZ Yeah, my comment was too early, which is unsurprising for exactly the reasons you state. These weren't any of the “big ones,” e.g. the ones now included in Unicode, but probably were the ones in the book White Wolf (or their artist) happened to be able to get their hands on in the pre-internet age.

Comment: *something* about the symbol codes is off

Comment: @KRyan no, I couldn’t get a copy - but I did look up some of the symbols in other online collections and found them to be pretty on point, for example the entropy symbol is very close to the “rot” symbol.

Comment: Note: I see a weird empty square at the end of each line of your answer (presumably some Unicode symbol or something that I can't see). This might be an artifact of copying and pasting from somewhere else. (EDIT: I only saw this on my MacBook Pro; I don't see it on my Windows laptop.)